# Android room doesn't return any data on first call

Tags: android, android-room

I have this chunk of code in my activity's onCreate:

```
MainActivity.mViewModel.getTransactionsByDateId(dateId).observe(this, data -> {
            transacs.addAll(data);
        });
```

Where `transacs` is just a list of type Transaction (db entity).     `getTransactionsByDateId` calls this code:

`@Query("SELECT * from transactions_table where dates_id = :dateId")`
`LiveData<List<Transactions>> getTransactionsByDateId(int dateId);`

When I open activity for the first time, data is empty. But when I open it for the second time, it's populated. I know Room is async, but is there a way to avoid this kind of behaviour as I need this data right on start of the activity?

Comment: add your full code. what is transacs? how you are updating your view.

Comment: I modified the question